# Specify number of CPUs for a job on SLURM

Tags: slurm

I would like to run multiple jobs on a single node on my cluster. However, when I submit a job, it takes all available CPUs and so remaining jobs are queued. As an example, I made a script that request few resources and submit two jobs that are supposed to run at the same time.

```
    #! /bin/bash
    variable=$(seq 0 1 1)
    for l in ${variable}
    do

    run_thread="./run_thread.sh"
    cat << EOF >  ${run_thread}
    #! /bin/bash
    #SBATCH -p normal 
    #SBATCH --nodes 1 
    #SBATCH --cpus-per-task 1
    #SBATCH --ntasks 1 
    #SBATCH --threads-per-core 1
    #SBATCH --mem=10G

    sleep 120

    EOF
    sbatch ${run_thread}
    done
```

However, one job is running and the other user is pending:

```
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
57    normal run_thre  user PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
56    normal run_thre  user  R       0:02      1 node00
```

The cluster only has one node with 4 sockets with 12 cores and 2 threads each. the output of command `scontrol show jobid #job` is the following:

```
    JobId=56 JobName=run_thread.sh
       UserId=user(1002) GroupId=user(1002) MCS_label=N/A
       Priority=4294901755 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=(null)
       JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
       Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
       RunTime=00:00:51 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
       SubmitTime=2018-03-24T15:34:46 EligibleTime=2018-03-24T15:34:46
       StartTime=2018-03-24T15:34:46 EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
       PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
       Partition=normal AllocNode:Sid=node00:13047
       ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
       NodeList=node00
       BatchHost=node00
       NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=48 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:1
       TRES=cpu=48,mem=10G,node=1
       Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
       MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=10G MinTmpDiskNode=0
       Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
       Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
       OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
       Command=./run_thread.sh
       WorkDir=/home/user
       StdErr=/home/user/slurm-56.out
       StdIn=/dev/null
       StdOut=/home/user/slurm-56.out
       Power=
```

And the output of `scontrol show partition` is:

```
    PartitionName=normal
       AllowGroups=ALL AllowAccounts=ALL AllowQos=ALL
       AllocNodes=ALL Default=YES QoS=N/A
       DefaultTime=NONE DisableRootJobs=NO ExclusiveUser=NO GraceTime=0 Hidden=NO
       MaxNodes=UNLIMITED MaxTime=UNLIMITED MinNodes=1 LLN=NO MaxCPUsPerNode=UNLIMITED
       Nodes=node00
       PriorityJobFactor=1 PriorityTier=1 RootOnly=NO ReqResv=NO OverSubscribe=YES:4
       OverTimeLimit=NONE PreemptMode=OFF
       State=UP TotalCPUs=48 TotalNodes=1 SelectTypeParameters=NONE
       DefMemPerNode=UNLIMITED MaxMemPerNode=UNLIMITED
```

There is something I don't get with the SLURM system. How can I use only 1 CPU per job and run 48 jobs on the node at the same time?

Comment: You might use `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I might, but what for?

Comment: `grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc`  is counting the number of cores.

Comment: It's actually counting the number of threads. But it does nothing in preventing slurm to use all 48 threads for a single thread job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm is probably configured with

```
SelectType=select/linear
```

which means that slurm allocates full nodes to jobs and does not allow node sharing among jobs.

You can check with

```
scontrol show config | grep SelectType
```

Set a value of `select/cons_res`  to allow node sharing.

Comment: Setting CPU as a consommable siwth SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU did the trick. Thank you !